# UITableView tableView cell separator is not showing in group style ios 7

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a problem in displaying cell separator of grouped style tableView in iOS 7.

```
if ([projectTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [projectTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        projectTable.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

This doesn't show cell separator. Kindly suggest

Comment: Try to force setting the separator style : `[projectTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine]`

Answer (score 10):

In **iOS7** design. try to do the below:

```
[projectTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

and also you have to do:

```
[projectTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

You can set the '**`Separator Inset'`** from the `nib or Storyboard`:

[image]

Comment: I am using nib file and not geting separator insets options.

Comment: @NabeelThobani: separator insets is draw seprator line same like <ios6 only. you have to set seprator property of tableview as "defualt or UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine"(like display above image 1st square).

Comment: There seems to be a bug in iOS 8. I tested this in both iOS 7 and iOS 8. Here are the results - [iOS 7](http://i.imgur.com/czINe0t.png), [iOS 8](http://i.imgur.com/2xgOd3d.png). As you can see in iOS 7 it works as expected but there is a glitch in iOS 8, the custom inset is applied only to the cell with no text.

Comment: @Isuru i didn't check it in ios 8.sorry for it

Answer (score 0):

Even though it has a default value (`UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`), have you tried reseting your `separatorStyle` property ?

```
[projectTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];
```

Comment: Ok. If you're overriding the `layoutSubviews` method be sure to call `[super layoutSubviews]`.